# map json values / dictionary to different functions

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop, google-api

I currently have a json file structured as so.

```
[
    {
      "jumpcloud-group-name":"Gsuite-Team",
      "jumpcloud-group-id":"abcde123455d2f4",
      "google-group-name":"test@somewebsite.com"
    },
    {
      "jumpcloud-group-name":"Gsuite-Team2",
      "jumpcloud-group-id":"abcde12345asdasdaasdasd",
      "google-group-name":"test1@somewebsite.com"
    }
  ]
```

I am wanting to map the different values of the same keys to different functions.

example: jumpcloud-group-id to group_id and google-group-name to groupkey

*both fields need to be strings and i have already used json load to import the json file to a dictionary. I have tried using a for loop however, I am confused on how to map everything with the same dictionary values

```
def jumpcloud_group_membership_ids():
    group_id = '5d2fsassfdasdasde9aa0ec' 

def main():
    groupKey = test@domain.com
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the tag of "google-apps-script"? You want to achieve your goal using "google-apps-script"?

Comment: I am using the google apI and wanted to add another tag.

Comment: this is part of a bigger project that I am working on and have a couple hundred lines of code and didn't want to add all of the code here

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you wanted to achieve your goal without using Google Apps Script. About your goal, I think that when you provide a sample input and output values you expect and your current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.